# Jquery ui automplete + json data from php

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make autocomplete of a field with jquery ui autocomplete and json, data from php file... But can't get any results...

Here is my jquery code:

```
$('#rech_abo').keyup(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $( ".find_group_ac" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/chercheabo",
                    data: {achercher : $("#rech_abo").val()},
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(obj) {
                            return {
                                label: obj.pseuDO,
                                value: obj.userID,
                               // description: obj.description
                               // id: obj.userID // don't really need this unless you're using it elsewhere.
                            };
                        }));
                    }

                });
            }
        }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            // Inside of _renderItem you can use any property that exists on each item that we built
            // with $.map above */
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.description + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
        });
```

My php:

```
$options = array();
$result = mysqli_query($link,"select userid, pseudo from utilisateurs where pseudo like '%".strtolower($_POST[achercher])."%'");
while($uti = $result->fetch_object()) {

    $options['myData'][] = array(
        'userID' => $uti->userid,
        'pseuDO'    => $uti->pseudo,
        'retourDATA' => $retour_data
    );
}

echo json_encode($options);
```

And my html:

```
<div class=\"abo_parnom\"><input class=\"input_text_compte\" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Tappez un nom\" id=\"rech_abo\"> <input type=\"button\" id=\"rech_abo_valider\" class=\"bouton_suppr\" value=\"Ok\"></div>
```

Any idea what is missing here?
Thanks

Comment: Autocomplete uses `term` to do it's search. Try replacing `$_POST[achercher]` with `$_POST['term']`.

Comment: Have you tested your query the way it is standalone? Do you get any JSON response from the AJAX call in your console? Are there any errors? Why doesn't your URL have a file extension?

Comment: If I remove the `data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item )`, I get no message in console. If I let it I have `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of null `

I have no file extension  because it is url rewrite